# Drupal 7 vbo, is there an option to input text to operations?

Tags: views

Im using VBO with drupal 7. If I have an action which creates a new node/update a new/create a comment etc. How can I manually type the title/body text or what ever it is I'm setting?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with Rules for example, every "Action set" Rules component that you create is exposed to Views Bulk Operations and all the parameters you configure for your action set will be available for use in the view.

I've created a simple view listing all nodes and an action set that exposes the title so you can modify it with a textbox.

Here's the view:

```
$view = new view();
$view->name = 'vbo_test';
$view->description = '';
$view->tag = 'default';
$view->base_table = 'node';
$view->human_name = 'VBO_Test';
$view->core = 7;
$view->api_version = '3.0';
$view->disabled = FALSE; /* Edit this to true to make a default view disabled initially */

/* Display: Master */
$handler = $view->new_display('default', 'Master', 'default');
$handler->display->display_options['title'] = 'VBO_Test';
$handler->display->display_options['use_more_always'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['access']['type'] = 'perm';
$handler->display->display_options['cache']['type'] = 'none';
$handler->display->display_options['query']['type'] = 'views_query';
$handler->display->display_options['exposed_form']['type'] = 'basic';
$handler->display->display_options['pager']['type'] = 'full';
$handler->display->display_options['pager']['options']['items_per_page'] = '10';
$handler->display->display_options['style_plugin'] = 'table';
$handler->display->display_options['style_options']['columns'] = array(
  'title' => 'title',
  'views_bulk_operations' => 'views_bulk_operations',
);
$handler->display->display_options['style_options']['default'] = '-1';
$handler->display->display_options['style_options']['info'] = array(
  'title' => array(
    'sortable' => 0,
    'default_sort_order' => 'asc',
    'align' => '',
    'separator' => '',
    'empty_column' => 0,
  ),
  'views_bulk_operations' => array(
    'align' => '',
    'separator' => '',
    'empty_column' => 0,
  ),
);
/* Field: Content: Bulk operations */
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['views_bulk_operations']['id'] = 'views_bulk_operations';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['views_bulk_operations']['table'] = 'node';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['views_bulk_operations']['field'] = 'views_bulk_operations';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['views_bulk_operations']['label'] = '';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['views_bulk_operations']['element_label_colon'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['views_bulk_operations']['vbo']['entity_load_capacity'] = '10';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['views_bulk_operations']['vbo']['operations'] = array(
  'action::node_assign_owner_action' => array(
    'selected' => 0,
    'use_queue' => 0,
    'skip_confirmation' => 0,
    'override_label' => 0,
    'label' => '',
  ),
  'action::views_bulk_operations_delete_item' => array(
    'selected' => 0,
    'use_queue' => 0,
    'skip_confirmation' => 0,
    'override_label' => 0,
    'label' => '',
  ),
  'action::system_message_action' => array(
    'selected' => 0,
    'use_queue' => 0,
    'skip_confirmation' => 0,
    'override_label' => 0,
    'label' => '',
  ),
  'action::views_bulk_operations_script_action' => array(
    'selected' => 0,
    'use_queue' => 0,
    'skip_confirmation' => 0,
    'override_label' => 0,
    'label' => '',
  ),
  'action::node_make_sticky_action' => array(
    'selected' => 0,
    'use_queue' => 0,
    'skip_confirmation' => 0,
    'override_label' => 0,
    'label' => '',
  ),
  'action::node_make_unsticky_action' => array(
    'selected' => 0,
    'use_queue' => 0,
    'skip_confirmation' => 0,
    'override_label' => 0,
    'label' => '',
  ),
  'action::views_bulk_operations_argument_selector_action' => array(
    'selected' => 0,
    'skip_confirmation' => 0,
    'override_label' => 0,
    'label' => '',
    'settings' => array(
      'url' => '',
    ),
  ),
  'action::node_promote_action' => array(
    'selected' => 0,
    'use_queue' => 0,
    'skip_confirmation' => 0,
    'override_label' => 0,
    'label' => '',
  ),
  'action::node_publish_action' => array(
    'selected' => 0,
    'use_queue' => 0,
    'skip_confirmation' => 0,
    'override_label' => 0,
    'label' => '',
  ),
  'action::system_goto_action' => array(
    'selected' => 0,
    'use_queue' => 0,
    'skip_confirmation' => 0,
    'override_label' => 0,
    'label' => '',
  ),
  'action::node_unpromote_action' => array(
    'selected' => 0,
    'use_queue' => 0,
    'skip_confirmation' => 0,
    'override_label' => 0,
    'label' => '',
  ),
  'action::node_save_action' => array(
    'selected' => 0,
    'use_queue' => 0,
    'skip_confirmation' => 0,
    'override_label' => 0,
    'label' => '',
  ),
  'action::system_send_email_action' => array(
    'selected' => 0,
    'use_queue' => 0,
    'skip_confirmation' => 0,
    'override_label' => 0,
    'label' => '',
  ),
  'action::node_unpublish_action' => array(
    'selected' => 0,
    'use_queue' => 0,
    'skip_confirmation' => 0,
    'override_label' => 0,
    'label' => '',
  ),
  'action::node_unpublish_by_keyword_action' => array(
    'selected' => 0,
    'use_queue' => 0,
    'skip_confirmation' => 0,
    'override_label' => 0,
    'label' => '',
  ),
  'rules_component::rules_vbo_test' => array(
    'selected' => 1,
    'use_queue' => 0,
    'skip_confirmation' => 0,
    'override_label' => 0,
    'label' => '',
  ),
);
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['views_bulk_operations']['vbo']['enable_select_all_pages'] = 1;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['views_bulk_operations']['vbo']['display_type'] = '0';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['views_bulk_operations']['vbo']['display_result'] = 1;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['views_bulk_operations']['vbo']['merge_single_action'] = 0;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['views_bulk_operations']['vbo']['force_single'] = 0;
/* Field: Content: Title */
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['title']['id'] = 'title';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['title']['table'] = 'node';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['title']['field'] = 'title';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['title']['label'] = '';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['title']['alter']['word_boundary'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['title']['alter']['ellipsis'] = FALSE;

/* Display: Page */
$handler = $view->new_display('page', 'Page', 'page');
$handler->display->display_options['path'] = 'vbo-test';
```

And here's the action set:

```
{ "rules_vbo_test" : {
    "LABEL" : "VBO_TEST",
    "PLUGIN" : "action set",
    "REQUIRES" : [ "rules" ],
    "USES VARIABLES" : {
      "node" : { "label" : "Node", "type" : "node" },
      "title" : { "label" : "title", "type" : "text" }
    },
    "ACTION SET" : [ { "data_set" : { "data" : [ "node:title" ], "value" : [ "title" ] } } ]
  }
}
```

More info can be found in this nodeone screencast: http://nodeone.se/en/using-rules-components-with-vbo

If you need to update the value of a field that is not available in the action set, you can expose "Rule sets" as well to VBO, that allows you to use conditions, particularly the Entity has field condition that will pull the field out of the entity and make it available to Rules UI:

```
    { "rules_test_rule_set" : {
    "LABEL" : "Test Rule set",
    "PLUGIN" : "rule set",
    "REQUIRES" : [ "rules" ],
    "USES VARIABLES" : {
      "node" : { "label" : "node", "type" : "node" },
      "text" : { "label" : "text", "type" : "text" }
    },
    "RULES" : [
      { "RULE" : {
          "IF" : [
            { "entity_has_field" : { "entity" : [ "node" ], "field" : "field_options" } }
          ],
          "DO" : [
            { "data_set" : { "data" : [ "node:field-options" ], "value" : [ "text" ] } }
          ],
          "LABEL" : "my rule"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

You can do this with arbitrary fields based in a data type that rules have info about, what I don't think you can configure is the widget exposed for this operation.

Comment: Hi Thank you for taking the time for this. Where did that text field come from, is it by default? If I wanted to update a checklist would that display?

Comment: Alternatively you can expose rule sets too. For that case you're asking, you need to use "Entity has field" condition to pull the field out of the entity because Rules doesn't do that out of the box. Editing my answer above.